# Overwrite an empty field value on node / rendered entity

Tags: 8

I have a text field in a media image type (for a photo caption) - I'd like to *output* a default value whenever it's empty.

I tried using *HOOK_preprocess_field*, but that hook isn't reached if the field of the node is blank.

It's being inserted in a View, but it's more than one field (a display mode of a Rendered Entity showing a photo thumbnail and the caption) and therefore as the photo is present when the caption isn't, I can't use the *No results behaviour*.

I also tried *HOOK_preprocess_node* and *HOOK_preproces_content_field*, neither of those seem to be called *at all* in the view.

Is there anywhere else I can edit it?

Comment: The text fiels is in the media image so i thinks the hook `theme_preprocess_media` is the right one

Comment: @berramou thanks - yes, it's that hook, I can rewrite populated fields by changing [0]['#context']['value'], unfortunately $variables['content']['field_caption'] has almost nothing in it for the blank field -  I've just spent ages trying to manually recreate all the fields in the array, but I then get *Call to a member function getFieldDefinition() on null in quickedit_preprocess_field()*, not sure if there's a method I could use to do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider overriding an appropriate Twig template, something along the lines of `{% if content.field_caption %} {{ content.field_caption }} {% else %}} default text {% endif %}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hook `theme_preprocess_media` check on media if it's an image and than get the default value of your field to compare it with the actual value.
Try the following.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function myTheme_preprocess_media(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\media\MediaInterface $media */
  $media = $variables['media'];
  if ($media->getSource()->getPluginId() === 'image') {
    $elements = $variables['elements'];
    if ($media->hasField('field_caption') && isset($elements['field_caption'])) {
      // Get the default value of field_caption field.
      // To compare it with the the actual value.
      $caption_default_value = $elements['field_caption']['#items']->first()
        ->getFieldDefinition()
        ->getDefaultValue($media)[0]['value'];
      // Get the actual value.
      $caption_actual_value = $media->field_caption->getValue()[0]['value'];

      // Check if the value hasn't change so its has the default value.
     if ($caption_default_value === $caption_actual_value){
       // Change the value of caption  field.
       $variables['content']['field_caption'][0]['#context']['value'] = t('This is new value of caption');
     }
    }
  }
}
```